# how to use next js obfuscator to obfuscate our file

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

How can I use obfuscator in Next.js and how will I get to know if my file is being obfuscated or not?

I tried to do this but I didn't see any changes?

```js
const NextJsObfuscatorPlugin= require("nextjs-obfuscator");
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,

}

module.exports ={
      webpack:(config,{dev})=>{
        if(!dev){
          config.plugins.push(new NextJsObfuscatorPlugin({
            rotateStringArray: true
          }))
        }
        return config
      } 
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you run a production build?

Comment: no i didn't run a production build

Comment: It'll only work in production builds

Comment: okay so after the deployment of my app it'll work??

Answer (score 1):

In this line `if(!dev)`, the condition is only satisfied in production, for example:

```bash
next build
next start -p 8888
```

> [dev](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/webpack)  Indicates if the compilation will be done in development

Another issue in your config file is the `nextConfig` variable is not used in the export. It should be

```js
module.exports ={
  webpack: (config,{dev})=>{/* ... */},

  ...nextConfig 

}
```